# Set Corba timeout in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, corba

Calling from a jar client to code allocated in an EJB, after 30 minutes executing code inside the EJB, I receive a timeout:

```
com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaResponseWaitingRoomImpl waitForResponse
WARNING: "IOP00410219: (COMM_FAILURE) Communications timeout waiting for response.  Exceeded 1,800,000 milliseconds"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 219 completed: Maybe
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.communicationsTimeoutWaitingForResponse(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3180)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.communicationsTimeoutWaitingForResponse(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3195)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaResponseWaitingRoomImpl.waitForResponse(CorbaResponseWaitingRoomImpl.java:198)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.waitForResponse(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1196)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.waitForResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:291)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete1(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:389)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:357)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:219)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:192)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
            at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(BCELStubBase.java:225)

    ...

    javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA COMM_FAILURE 1398079707 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 219 completed: Maybe
    java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA COMM_FAILURE 1398079707 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 219 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:271)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:205)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(BCELStubBase.java:225)
```

I am using Glassfish 2.1, Java 1.6_20. Is there a way to define this timeout to one hour for example? Is this Glassfish dependent? Some configuration maybe?

Thank you for your help in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a property to a your URL like this:

http://test.com/Client?prop=**com.sun.corba.ee.transport.ORBWaitForResponseTimeout=7200000**

There are additional settings you can set for the JVM described in [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/ejcorba/entry/more_on_tcp_timeouts_in) but I'm not sure if they will work with your version of glassfish.

Comment: Thank you for answering unwichtich. I could not manage to make the parameter work. But I have been trying to optimize the process instead :D